# gVim: Pathogen not loading plugins properly (Windows)

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, vim-plugins

I'm using gVim 7.4 on Windows 7 x64. When I place a plugin in the bundle folder, the plugin's commands don't seem to be registered. My setup is as follows:

gVim is installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74`.

I placed the pathogen file here: `C:\Users\gordon\vimfiles\autoload\pathogen.vim`.

I want to use the NERD Tree plugin so I executed the following in a command prompt:

```
cd C:\Users\gordon\vimfiles\bundle
git clone https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git
```

That created the folder `C:\Users\gordon\vimfiles\bundle\nerdtree` with all the NERD Tree plugin folders beneath it.

I also installed the zenburn colour scheme:

```
cd C:\Users\gordon\vimfiles\bundle
git clone https://github.com/jnurmine/Zenburn.git zenburn
```

My `C:\Users\gordon\_gvimrc` file contains the following:

```
set nocompatible
execute pathogen#infect()
filetype plugin on
filetype plugin indent on
set guifont=Dina:h10:cANSI
colors zenburn
```

I do not get any errors when launching gVim. The weird thing is that pathogen must be working because the zenburn colour scheme is loaded without a problem, and I can open the NERD Tree help with `:help NERD_tree.txt`, but when I try to actually launch NERD Tree the command is unrecognised:

```
:NERDTree
E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree
```

I've read many posts online about getting pathogen and plugins working and from what I can tell all the files are in the correct place. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Rename `C:\Users\gordon\_gvimrc` to `C:\Users\gordon\_vimrc`.

Comment: @romainl Thank you, that worked! Wonder why it doesn't work when using _gvimrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_gvimrc` is sourced very late in the startup process, way after `_vimrc` and after your plugins are loaded. Anything you put there will happen to late.

Also, `_gvimrc` should be used *only* for GUI-specific settings: everything that applies to both Vim *and* GVim should be in `_vimrc`.

Rename `C:\Users\gordon\_gvimrc` to `C:\Users\gordon\_vimrc`to fix your problem.